# PostgreSQL "forgets" default schema when closing data source connection

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am running into a very strange issue with Spring Boot and Spring Data: after I manually close a connection, the formerly working application seems to "forget" which schema it's using and complains about missing relations.

Here's the code snippet in question:

```
try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection()) {
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new ClassPathResource("/script.sql"));
}
```

This code works fine, but after it executes, the application immediately starts throwing errors like the following:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "some_table" does not exist
```

Prior to executing the code above, the application works fine (including referencing the table it later complains about). If I remove the try-resource block, and do not close the Connection, everything also works fine, except that I've now created a resource leak. I have also tried explicitly setting the default schema (public) in the following ways:

- In the JDBC URL with the `currentSchema` parameter
- With the the `spring.datasource.hikari.schema` parameter
- With the `spring.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` property

The last does alleviate the issue with respect to Hibernate managed classes, but the issue persists with native queries. I could, of course, make the schema explicit in those queries, but that doesn't seem to address the root issue. Why would closing a connection trigger this behavior?

My environment:

- Spring Boot 2.5.1
- PostgreSQL 12.7

Comment: What is in that script? Does it alter the default search path? Does the schema you want to use actually occur on your default search path? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the `search_path` of the user you are using? Sounds as if that was changed from the default. You can set it permanently through `alter user set search_path = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to several users above who immediately saw what I did not. The script, adapted from an older pg_dump run, was indeed mucking with the search_path:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

Removing that line, and some other unnecessary ones, resolved the problem. Big  duh on my part.